# Приведение Dictionary

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста почему dB равен null ? не могу понять(

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {            
    }
    public int _a;
}

class B: A
{
    public B(int b)
    {
       _a = _b = b;
    }
    public int _b;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dA = new Dictionary<string, A>();
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dA.Add(i.ToString(), new B(i));

        var dB = ((object)dA) as Dictionary<string, B>;            
    }
}
```

Comment: В этом коде все нормально. У себя запустил: dB **не равен** null

Comment: дико извиняюсь, поправил.

Comment: Окей, новый код. Ну, каст не проходит, потому что `Dictionary<string, A>` _не является_ `Dictionary<string, B>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Формальная причина**: каст не проходит, потому что `Dictionary<string, A>` не является `Dictionary<string, B>` или производным от него типом.

[Для специалистов: Несмотря на то, что `B` — производный от `A` тип (то есть, `B` *является* `A`), `Dictionary<K, V>` не контравариантен по `V`.]

**Мотивация** (почему собственно нельзя?):

Представьте себе, что так было бы можно. Рассмотрим такой код:

```
var dA = new Dictionary<string, A>();
dA.Add("0", new A());

Dictionary<string, B> dB = ((object)dA) as Dictionary<string, B>;
// пусть здесь dB != null
B bval = dB["0"]; // <-------------
bval._b = 100;
```

Что произойдёт в предпоследней строке? Объект по ключу `"0"` есть. Поскольку тип у `dB` — `Dictionary<string, B>`, то тип значения по ключу обязан быть `B`. Таким образом, присваивание переменной `B bval` должно быть в порядке, код должен скомпилироваться.

Но реально-то в словаре объект типа `A`, а не `B`! То есть мы смогли нарушить типизацию. Катастрофа! Что делать системе в *последней* строке? Ничего умного в голову не приходит.

Именно поэтому такое и не разрешено.

Comment: но в моем случае в dA  в значениях словаря хранятся ссылки именно на объекты B ведь.

Comment: @Serg: То есть вы предлагаете, чтобы код `as` **во время выполнения** проверял, можно ли как-нибудь безопасно представить **конкретный** экземпляр `Dictionary<string, A>` в виде `Dictionary<string, B>`? А если вы **потом** добавите в `dA` экземпляр `A`, он не должен появиться в `dB`, хотя они ссылаются на один и тот же объект? `as` работает не так, решение принимается на основе _типов_ объектов, и только на их основе. Текущее содержимое объектов в расчёт не берётся.